# Bringing my parents car to Denmark

Tags: taxes, students, car, vehicle-registration, denmark

I'm looking for an answer on the following question. I'm starting a study next September in Denmark (not in Copenhagen) and my parents want to give me a car to drive so I can come home a few times during the year (I'm dutch). It will be registered on their name, and I'll probably won't be driving it a lot in Denmark.

As it officially won't be my car, will I still get problems with it not being Danish? I can't really find any information on that particular matter.

I hope you can help me on a short notice.

With kind regards, 
Annemarie

Comment: It's been a while, but can you post an update on how things went for you? I find myself in the same situation and I don't know what to do.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a process, a form to complete, and a payment (DKK 400), with comprehensive all the information found at [SKAT.dk](http://skat.dk/SKAT.aspx?oId=1716067&vId=0)

> Application for permission to drive a foreign-registered motor vehicle in Denmark, Form no. 21.059 EN
>
> **About this form**
>   You must complete this form to apply for permission to drive a foreign-registered vehicle in Denmark. You will typically need this permission if you are staying temporarily in Denmark as a student or because of short-term employment.
>
> Please complete the form and send it to:
>
> SKAT, Motor
>  
>   Helgeshøj Allé 9
>  
>   2630 Taastrup
>  
>   Denmark
>
> A fee of DKK 400 is charged for applying for the permission.
>
> You can pay the DKK 400 by transferring the amount via online banking using "card type: +73" and "account no.: 86984156".
>
> Please attach the following information in the payment:
>
> - applicant's CPR number (civil reg. no.)
> - applicant's name
> - vehicle registration number
> - reference number (if applicable)
>     We need this information to be able to identify which payment relates to your application.
>
> Note: Please enclose the following documents when submitting your application:
>
> - Copy of the vehicle registration certificate
> - Documentation of your stay in Denmark, for example an employment contract
> - Receipt for paying the DKK 400 fee.
>
> Complete the form online by clicking the first field and filling it in. Use the tab key to jump to the next field. Remember to enclose a copy of the vehicle registration certificate and documentation of the purpose and duration of your stay, for example an employment contract.
>
> Remember to state your civil registration number (CPR number). If you do not provide your civil registration number, your application cannot be processed  - unless in special circumstances, if for example you are working in Denmark for a foreign company which is registered in the Register of Foreign Service Providers.
>
> **Persons residing in Denmark**
>
> A person residing in Denmark is generally not allowed to use a foreign-registered vehicle for driving in Denmark.
>
> Permission may be granted to persons residing in Denmark, but working outside Denmark on weekdays. The permission only covers driving from a border crossing to the person's residence in Denmark and back in connection with holidays. The vehicle may not be used for any other transport in Denmark.
>
> A foreigner coming to live in Denmark may use a foreign-registered vehicle in Denmark for a period of 30 days from the date of entry to Denmark, after which the vehicle must be either registered in Denmark or transported out of Denmark, or be deregistered.
>
> **Persons residing abroad**
>
> A person coming to Denmark for a limited period of up to 185 days may apply for permission to drive a foreign-registered vehicle during the stay in Denmark.
>
> If the stay is your first in Denmark, and it is not expected to exceed 185 days, you may drive a foreign-registered vehicle during your stay in Denmark. You must always bring documentation for the duration of your stay with you while driving (for example a copy of your employment contract). You do not need to apply for permission in such situations.
>
> If your stay exceeds 185 days, the vehicle must generally be registered in Denmark (and you must pay registration tax) or be transported out of Denmark.
>
> If your stay in Denmark exceeds 185 days, but you are on a fixed-term assignment in Denmark, you may pay quarterly a proportion of the normal vehicle registration tax. For this purpose, you must complete form no. 21.033 EN.
>
> **Double domicile**
>
> If you reside in Denmark and another country at the same time, it must be determined which residence can be regarded as your usual place of residence, which is defined as the residence to which you have the strongest ties, i.e. the country where you are considered to be domiciled.
>
> This determination includes considering business and private ties and the amount of time spent in the particular country. If your strongest ties are to -Denmark, you will be considered to be residing in Denmark and may therefore not use a vehicle with foreign number plates in Denmark.
>
> PDF version    [Application 21.059 EN](https://skat.dk/getFile.aspx?Id=130238)